# Raspberry pi 3 + raspbian + firefox esr very slow

Tags: raspbian, web-browsers

Hello everyone I have the Raspberry pi 3 with the raspbian system. I have installed the Firefox ESR browser and icewaesel -> Firefox ESR.
Every time I open it I slow down a lot the raspberry and I can not open two windows in a row without being blocked for minutes.
How can I make it go faster or thinner?

Comment: perform this test. run the two firefox windows and post screenshot of `top` command in terminal, output of `df` command to see fs usage, and output of `free -mh` command to show memory usage.

Comment: Also, for good measure, perform a system update `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y` to clean up any outdated packages

Answer (score 1):

Web browsing on a Raspberry Pi is slow, but it's certainly not normal to wait for *minutes* for a new window to open. I suggest you make a fresh install with no extra software except for Firefox (no addons!), and retry.

If opening a new window (except the first one) still takes more than a few seconds, I would try getting a different SD card.

Comment: I am literally using a brand new install so I don't think it has anything to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having this problem for as long as I got my Rpi and I was very upset with it.

It is slow because it uses SD card for the main hard drive.  I suspected this for a long time but I could not get my head around it since it would be slow has soon as I would access any, any website.

Firefox and Chrome will cache website hence will write on a slow device cached information and will put on hold Firefox will writing to the "SLOW" device.

Just deactivate cache in preferences and history too... anything that writes to the disk, or use a faster device SD card or USB key mounted for your personnal directory.

It worked for me.

Good luck.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chromium Browser which is the default browser of Latest Raspbian.

If you haven't update your os with Pixel you can upgrade it.

more details about pixel you can find from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/):

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my RPi 3+ with a SSD as maindrive.
The system is up to date (update&upgrade)

I used "top" to find out that swap was running out of free space evertime I used firefox with some tabs open wich contained very active webcontent (java)
After augmentation of swapspace to 500MB (/etc/dphys-swapfile , standard is 100) at least raspian doesn't freeze anymore and after execution I can close windows to make system faster again.

I hope this will help.